# How can I remove all occurrences of a command while keeping the argument?

Tags: macros, l3regex

I have a tex file with several occurrences of a command `\add{...}` that I defined myself. This command takes text strings as argument and colors them differently (\textcolor{red}{#1} for example). Now I need to remove all of these commands while keeping the arguments themselves intact. I can think of roundabout ways of doing this; simply removing all occurrences of `\add` and letting the matched `{` and `}` remain floating in the document. Or even changing the definition of the `\add` command so that it colors the argument in the default color of the document.

What I want to know is some way of fully removing the `\add` commands from my document, including the braces. I have been careful to only use my command on text strings and never any math or referencing so that there are no nested braces inside the `\add{...}` parts. I think that should mean some regex-like technique could solve my problem?

(Just to be clear, I know that this `\add` way to mark revisions is vastly inferior to using latexdiff, but there is only so much I'm willing to argue about with my prof.)

Comment: Do you want the source code modified or merely the typeset result?  If the latter, merely `\renewcommand\add[1]{#1}`

Comment: I want the source code modified, the typeset result is easy to revert.

Comment: Easiest solution: `\makeatletter\let\add\@firstofone\makeatother`. `\add` will remove the braces when it is used. Some VIM-like regular expression: `:%s/\\add{\(.\{,}\)}/\1/g` to remove `\add` as you want from the sources.

Comment: Might be interesting on which OS you are, so we have an idea of the available tools. *But* asking for this doesn't seem on topic here and would be better suited elsewhere in the network (basically this isn't TeX specific, you just ask on how to apply regular expressions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can run `perl`, you can use the following to get what you want:

```sh
perl -pi.bak -e 's/\\add{(.*?)}/\1/g' <filename>
```

This will run `perl`, back up the file as `<filename>.bak`, and replace every occurence of `\\add{<stuff>}` with `<stuff>` (and nested braces will make it fail, but you said you don't have nested braces).

Comment: Great, I'm on Windows and do have Perl. Thanks.

Comment: @AritraDas keep in mind that this works line-wise, so if the argument of `\add` spans multiple lines this will fail as well (well, not fail, just not remove it).